# compare two arrays in reactjs

Tags: arrays, reactjs, checkbox

I have this code: in reactjs
http://codepen.io/fernandooj/pen/MJOodr

```
1- list an array, when mapping I send each item a checkbox
2- I have another array that I still do not have
3- I need to compare the two arrays and if there is an element of both arrays
```

equal the checkbox that is repeated in list is active
example
Array1 [1,2,3]
Array2 [2]
The checkbox "2" appears cheked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `call a function with item` as a parameter so the the `defaultChecked` value. Make sure you dont bind the function because `defaultChecked` expects a value and not a function.

```
  getChecked(item) {
     console.log(item);
     if(array2.indexOf(item) > -1) {return true}
     return false;
   }
       <input 
            key={item} 
            name='list' 
            type='checkbox' 
            onClick={(e)=>this.updateStateList(e,item)}
            label='Add' 
            className='listTour'
            defaultChecked={this.getChecked(item)}/>
```

**[CodePen](http://codepen.io/mayank_shubham/pen/ggXXwJ)**